# What is the correct implementation for GetHashCode() for entity classes?

Tags: c#, .net, orm

Below is a sample implementation of overriding Object.Equals() for an entity base class from which all other entities in an application derive.

All entity classes have the property Id, which is a nullable int.  (It's the primary key of whatever table the entity class corresponds to.)

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            if (obj == null || GetType() != obj.GetType())
                return false;

            if (base.Equals(obj))
                return true;

            return Id.HasValue && ((EntityBase) obj).Id.HasValue &&
                   Id.Value == ((EntityBase) obj).Id.Value;
        }
```

Given this implementation of Equals(), how do you correctly implement GetHashCode()?

Comment: For the record, having a nullable int for an ID is a horrible idea.  IDs should virtually always be GUIDs and definitely not nullable.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you're deriving from something that already overrides `GetHashCode` I'd implement it as:

```
public override int GetHashCode()
{
    unchecked
    {
        int hash = 37;
        hash = hash * 23 + base.GetHashCode();
        hash = hash * 23 + Id.GetHashCode();
        return hash;
    }
}
```

A null value of Id will return 0 for Id.GetHashCode().

If your class just derives from Object, I'd just return `Id.GetHashCode()` - you do *not* want to include the `object.GetHashCode` implementation in your hash code, as that basically ends up being object identity.

Note that your equality definition *won't* return `true` if neither entity has an Id, but the same hashcode will be returned from both objects. You may wish to consider changing your Equals implementation.

Comment: For those wondering, like I did: The 23 and 37 are arbitrary numbers which are co-prime. Jon stated this in a similar answer here: http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/29483139/override-gethashcode.aspx

Comment: @JonSkeet wouldn't you agree that adding `base.GetHashCode()` would use Object.GetHashCode, which uses the memory address. In that case GetHashCode doesn't have the property that when Equals returns true for two objects, their hashCodes should be the same??

Comment: @JonSkeet I'd also add `unchecked {}` to hashcode implementations to avoid compiler options... It's an edge case you'd probably would never run into... Either way, the unchecked keyword is a way of documenting that integer overflows are ok in the function.

Comment: @Japp: if you're deriving directly from object, then you wouldn't want to use base.GetHashCode, indeed. See the second paragraph after the code. And yes, it would make sense to use unchecked.

Comment: @JonSkeet Why is it not necessary to also insert a specific value in the hashcode which represents the specific class of the object. I mean, this implementation results that two different objects of two different subclasses of the same base class but with the same ID return the same hashcode. Shouldn't we prevent this or isn't there a reason to prevent this? (I know that in a dictionary, after checking the `getHashCode`, the `Equals` method is evaluated which would be different)

Comment: @CodePope: While you *could* do that, I think it would be optimizing by avoiding a hash collision in a rare case, at a slight cost (an extra operation for *all* hash operations) for the more common case. Usually subclasses will add their own state, so that will perturb the hash anyway. Any code using GetHashCode should handle the fact that two objects with the same hash may not be equal, so really you're just trying to balance hash collisions with speed of computing the hash normally. It *certainly* isn't "necessary" to include a class-specific value - it *may* (in some niche cases) be useful.

Answer (score 2):

What Jon Skeet answered is a good solution, however, you might want to add an unchecked code block to allow integer overflowing

```
unchecked
{
  int hash = ...;
  return hash
}
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/khy08726(v=vs.140).aspx

> If neither checked nor unchecked is specified, the default context depends on external factors such as compiler options.

I'd also like to add, again, that using `base.GetHashCode()` on POCO's will call the default `object.GetHashCode`. That's definitely not what you want...

Comment: `unchecked` is the default and is unnecessary.

Comment: "If neither checked nor unchecked is specified, the default context depends on external factors such as compiler options."
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/khy08726(v=vs.140).aspx

So if you write such code, I'd put it there. It also is a form of documentation.

Comment: Have added the unchecked part to my own answer now, btw.

Answer (score 2):

What about using the type as part of the hash code?
Would this be a good implementation?

```
public class Foo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    // other properties here
    // ......

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        int hash = 37;
        hash = hash * 23 + typeof(Foo).GetHashCode();
        hash = hash * 23 + Id.GetHashCode();
        return hash;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can only correctly implement `GetHashCode()` if the `Id` property is immutable for the lifetime of an instance (or at least for the time that its hash needs to be used, such as while the object is in a map or other collection requiring the hash).

Assuming that it is, you can just use the value of `Id` as the hash for all valid values and then use a fixed hash for null.  I can't remember what the most appropriate is for this, but I would assume a randomly selected value for null(randomly selected prior to compilation, not at runtime) or the median value of valid `Id` values (i.e. halfway between 0 and int.Max).

Comment: It doesn't have to be immutable for the lifetime - only from the point at which it's first inserted into a map or whatever. It's okay to create an instance, mess around with it, put it into a map and *then* stop messing with it.