# Fast way to hash objects focussing on properties containing a certain attribute?

Tags: c#, serialization, hash, md5

I have created my own form of serialization which converts an object supplied to a string which I can then get an MD5 hash of. The hashing is used for a quick compare to see if specific properties have changed. However my code is extremely slow and I was wondering if anyone has any better ideas?

I need to *only* worry about the properties in the object marked with a custom [DatabaseMap] attribute. I'm not too concerned about the hashing method, but rather the way the object is serialized before being hashed.

Is there a better way of doing this?

```
    public static string GetHash(this IBaseObject source)
    {
        if (source == null)
            return string.Empty;

        // step 1, calculate MD5 hash from input
        var hasher = new ThreadLocal<MD5>(MD5.Create);
        byte[] inputBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(SerializeDataMembers(source, hasher)); // serialize the object
        byte[] hash = hasher.Value.ComputeHash(inputBytes);

        // step 2, convert byte array to hex string
       // StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
       // for (int i = 0; i < hash.Length; i++)
       // {
       //     sb.Append(hash[i].ToString("X2"));
       // }
       // return sb.ToString();  
        return BitConverter.ToString(hash);
    }

    private static string SerializeDataMembers(IBaseObject source, MD5 hasher)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        var properties = source.GetType().GetProperties();
        foreach (PropertyInfo prop in properties)
        {
            var attrs = Attribute.GetCustomAttributes(prop);
            if (attrs.OfType<DatabaseMap>().Any())
            {
                if (prop.PropertyType == typeof (byte[]))
                {
                    sb.Append(Convert.ToBase64String(hasher.ComputeHash((byte[])prop.GetValue(source))));
                }
                else
                {
                    sb.Append(prop.GetValue(source));
                }
            }
        }

        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: Why go through all the trouble of MD5 comparing objects when you can [override GetHashCode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/508126/what-is-the-correct-implementation-for-gethashcode-for-entity-classes).

Comment: I need a fast way to hash an object and then later generate a hash again to see if any property marked with a specific attribute has been changed. I initially serialized the object using ServiceStack.Text, however this serializes the whole object whereas I only care about certain properties. Then I came up with the solution above, but I am sure there are faster ways. The hashing method isn't the problem.

Comment: I think the proper would be to implement an [`IComparer(T)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ehhxeaf.aspx) for your interface that will get the attributes.

Comment: But I'm not comparing two objects. The use case is when the object is initialized I hash it - later on when someone wants to commit the object to a data store, another hash (on the same object) is created and then compared to the original hash. If these hashes differ then the commit occurs, otherwise nothing happens due to no changes being made.

Comment: What you're describing is analogous to the [Unit Of Work pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd882510.aspx).

Comment: Not really answering the question I've posed though...

Comment: What I was getting at is the `UnitOfWork` should track the changes to the `Entity` thus there is no need for expensive hash computations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Unit Of Work](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd882510.aspx) pattern gave me an idea. I completely removed any hashing, and for the particular attributed properties I care about, in their setter I compare if anything has changed from their old value to the new value and if it has I increment a counter. Speed is incredibly fast without hashing.

```
    private void CompareChange<T>(T old, T newValue)
    {
        if (!EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(old, newValue))
            Interlocked.Increment(ref _ChangeCount);
    }
```